# How to troubleshoot Kibana Time-Outs

Tags: elasticsearch, timeout, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have been experiencing an issue where occasionally my Kibana stops working stating a time-out trying to connect to elasticsearch as the cause. (I have marvel installed. Something like: "plugin:elasticsearch Request Timeout"

Usually these go away by the next day, and occasionally I have been able to re-gain access to my data by increasing the timeout on kibana. However I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this issue. I suspect it may be that ES is storing some extremely large individual documents but I cannot find them, there's just too many logs to dig through by hand.

My elasticsearch cluster is perfectly healthy (green on health check), even when kibana cannot access it.

Where can I possibly start to try and troubleshoot why we are getting timeouts here? when I expand the timeout window, kibana comes back, and everything works FINE.

Any tips on where to start searching would be enormously appreciated!!